# Catching names in a text

Tags: python, regex

I've got a problem finding the right regex.

With this regex,

```
([\.!?] |^|\n)(M\. \b.*?)\b[.,].*(?!(M\. )).*?([mM]adame l[ea] ministre)
```

I've got a corpus with names in the style 
"M. X. blablabla (what M. X says) M. Y. blablabla (what M. Y. says)"

I have to get occurrences of [mM]adame l[ae] ministre (feminine or masculine) inside their talking.

So for exemple M. Y says "Je suis madame la ministre" I want to catch :
"M. Y. Je suis madame la ministre"

But my regex catches "M. X. blablabla M. Y. Je suis madame la ministre"

Also, 
in M. X, X can be :
"Name Surname LongSurname-With-spécial-char"
or
"Long title of lengthy length"

For ex : 
https://regex101.com/r/XRCUwc/1

Should catch :
**M. Maurice Leroy.** Décidément non, l’imagination n’est pas au pouvoir ! (Exclamations sur les bancs du groupe socialiste.) « L’emploi ne se décrète pas », avez-vous écrit, **madame le ministre**

Please help me, I'm new to regex and they can be really abstract...

Comment: `M. Foobar. Blablabla M. Barfoo. Blublublu madame le ministre` @ that sentence why only catch M. Barfoo and not M. Foobar?

Comment: @Ludisposed I guess he wants M. Foobar as well, but he already catchs it with his current regex.

Comment: @Mistalis I think so, the description is a bit vague IMHO

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, it's hard to explain. I don't care about M. Foobar, I only want to catch "M. Barfoo. Blublublu madame le ministre".

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong but in your last example you want, everything in between the last person and madame le ministre? like from `M. Maurice` untill `le ministre`

Comment: Do names always begin with `M.` and end with `.`

Comment: @Ludisposed Yes exactly ! They begin with M. or Mme. and finish with . or ,

Comment: Updated my Answer, please take a look if this is more suitable to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Examaple@Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XRCUwc/13)

I think i know what you want, namely finding the last occurence of `Mr.` untill the next `madame le ministre`

**Pattern**

```
re.findall("M\.(?!.*M\.)(.*)[mM]adame l[ea] ministre", text)
```

> Match the characters «`M\.`»
>
> Negative lookahea) «`(?!.*M\.)`»
>
> Match any single character that is not a line break character «`(.*)`»
>
> Match the characters «`[mM]adame l[ea] ministre`»

I hope this is what you mean, maybe next time try to be more clear in your first try. Questions well asked are more worth putting time into ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Negative ahead means that .*M\. should not be after the preceding regex? I did a mix of your regex and Mistalis' regex so I can catch the name : (M\. [A-Z][A-zéè-]+( [A-Z][A-zéè-]+)?)(?!.*M\.)(.*)[mM]adame l[ea] ministre . Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I have a little trouble with your regex : It does work, but there is some trouble if there is M\. after madame la ministre. https://regex101.com/r/BxZZ9f/1 How can I avoid that ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BxZZ9f/7 But for some examples it doesn't work whereas the last regex works...... :/

Comment: it is ugly but a solution could be first using this pattern `(M\..*[mM]adame l[ea] ministre)` to find all untill ministre, and afterwards use the other pattern `M\.(?!.*M\.)(.*)[mM]adame l[ea] ministre` to find the what the last person said

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion that extract names from your text:

```
(M\. [A-Z][A-zéè-]+( [A-Z][A-zéè-]+)?)|([mM]adame l[ea] ministre)
```

It seeks for a `M.` followed by a firstname and a lastname (lastname is optional). Firstname and lastname are defined as string beginning with a capital letter (`[A-Z][a-z]+`).

It extracts from `M. Foobar. Blablabla M. Barfoo. Blublublu madame le ministre`:

```
M. Foobar
M. Barfoo
madame le ministre
```

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XRCUwc/11)

Comment: `M. Foobar Othername Maidenname Lastname` will not be catched, but not sure if that is what OP wants

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Ludisposed is right, I can have very long name or title, sometimes with "-" or spaces or accentuated chars (é, è....)

Comment: I would like to know who said "madame la ministre". I don't know if this can do it, maybe I can check the match before the "madame la ministre" match ? I've updated my original post for better explaination.